# What winged insect is in this photo? Is it Axymyia furcata?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Posting on behalf of a neighbor who asked:

> Can anyone identify this insect? It's about 3/8" long. There are, it seems, hundreds flitting low over our lawn. There were none 2 days ago.

This is the Northern California Bay Area Peninsula.

[image: Insect]

Comment: $\frac{3}{8}$'' is a weridly accurate measure so just to confirm, it was $\frac{3}{8}$ of an inch, that is 0.95 cm, is that right?

Comment: Yes, " indicates inches. So about 1 cm.

Comment: One concern is that they are swarming termites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My neighbor submitted the photo to http://bugguide.net and it was identified as a sugar cane soldier fly, 
"Inopus rubriceps"- Female

http://bugguide.net/node/view/1299782

They are from Australia and were accidentally introduced to San Francisco 50 years ago.  It feeds on grasses.

Answer (score 6):

Great pictures.  First, fly or wasp?

In the second picture, under the head you don't see jaws of a wasp, but do see a bit of a tongue-like organ, like a fly.  Further down, you can see that there are only 2 wings.  Just below where the left wing meets the thorax, you can see what looks like a tiny wing or paddle.  That's a haltere, a reduced wing that vibrates to provide stability, like a gyroscope.  Flys have halteres.  Finally, in the first picture at the very end of the abdomen are 2 points.  That ain't a stinger, it's an ovipositor.  It's a fly, female, and from the size of the abdomen, gravid.

The closest I've gotten to identifying this one is *Axymyia furcata* http://bugguide.net/node/view/1216479.  Everything matches, as well as we can see from a photo, except the coloration.  Also, *A furcata* is associated with streams and is found in the north-east and north-central US, while, your bug was found on a lawn in CA.  For more information about *A. furcata* than you need, there is a master's thesis available:  http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1882&context=etd.

I've looked at hundreds of fly pics to find the one I linked to above.  That's the only fly I found that matches the shape of yours.  Maybe it's a different fly within that genus, maybe it's just a color variation.

Their maggots live in rotten wood and decaying plant material, and the adults are mostly interested in more maggots, so this isn't a pest, just a neighbor.

Edit: furicata --> furcata, oops.

Comment: Can you fix furicata to furcata?  (I can't -- the edit isn't large enough.)